# How do I convert dict of dicts/nested dicts into dict of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Heres the original dict

```
uid_coins = {'141632864': {'username': 'Guest130679138', 'coins': 0}, 
        '141632884': {'username': 'Guest130679156', 'coins': 39123441}, 
        '141632886': {'username': 'Guest130679158', 'coins': 44006638}}
```

What I am trying to get

```
d = {'uid':[141632864, 141632884, 141632886], 
'username': ['Guest130679138', 'Guest130679156', 'Guest130679158'], 
'coins': [0, 39123441, 44006638]}
```

The keys in original dict represent uid.

This is my what I have done:

```
uid = list(uid_coins.keys())
username = [u_data['username'] for u_data in uid_coins.values()]
coins = [[u_data['coins'] for u_data in uid_coins.values()]]

d = {"uid":uid, "username":username, "coins":coins}


dict((key,d[key]) for d in data for key in d)
```

But I am rather looking for a generalized approach, to achieve without manually declaring the keys again, just so it should work with new keys in the original data.

Comment: What have you tried so far. Can you show the code thats not working and any error it gives or output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalized (based on original version by Andrej Kesely):

```
d = {}
for k, v in uid_coins.items():
    d.setdefault('uid', []).append(k)
    for i in v.keys():
        d.setdefault(i, []).append(v[i])
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
uid_coins = {
    "141632864": {"username": "Guest130679138", "coins": 0},
    "141632884": {"username": "Guest130679156", "coins": 39123441},
    "141632886": {"username": "Guest130679158", "coins": 44006638},
}

out = {}
for k, v in uid_coins.items():
    out.setdefault("uid", []).append(k)
    out.setdefault("username", []).append(v["username"])
    out.setdefault("coins", []).append(v["coins"])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{'uid': ['141632864', '141632884', '141632886'], 
 'username': ['Guest130679138', 'Guest130679156', 'Guest130679158'], 
 'coins': [0, 39123441, 44006638]}
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar version as @Andrej Kesely but with `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

uid_coins = {
    '141632864': {'username': 'Guest130679138', 'coins': 0}, 
    '141632884': {'username': 'Guest130679156', 'coins': 39123441}, 
    '141632886': {'username': 'Guest130679158', 'coins': 44006638}
}

d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in uid_coins.items():
    d['uid'].append(key)
    d['username'].append(value['username'])
    d['coins'].append(value['coins'])
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'uid': ['141632864', '141632884', '141632886'], 'username': ['Guest130679138', 'Guest130679156', 'Guest130679158'], 'coins': [0, 39123441, 44006638]})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get the output in desired format (as mentioned in question) from the given dictionary.

```
d = {'uid': list(uid_coins.keys()), 'username': [i['username'] for i in list(uid_coins.values())], 'coins': [i['coins'] for i in list(uid_coins.values())]}
```

`list(uid_coins.keys())` will return all your uids as list.

`[i['username'] for i in list(uid_coins.values())]` will return 'username' values as list.

`[i['coins'] for i in list(uid_coins.values())]` will return 'coins' values as list.

[image]